# MacVim how to disable arrow navigation?

Tags: vim, navigation, key

This a common question on the internet, but after a lot of research I still can't do it.

This is what I have on my .vimrc file:

```
 map <up> <nop>
 map <down> <nop>
 map <left> <nop>
 map <right> <nop>
 imap <up> <nop>
 imap <down> <nop>
 imap <left> <nop>
 imap <right> <nop>
```

And I still can move my courser using the arrow keys.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: This works for me. Check if `:verbose map <up>` says anything. Also check if your vimrc is being read properly as everything looks like it should work.

Comment: Here's a workaround: avoid those keys and use other ways to move around consciously.

Comment: Quick google brought up this [Habit breaking, habit making](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/02/habit-breaking-habit-making/)

Comment: Along the same lines as @FDinoff's comment, what happens if you try (for example) `:map <up> <nop>` at the command line instead of putting it in your vimrc file?

Comment: I tried :map <up> <nop> no the command line and it worked great, bit in the .vimrc it didn't

Comment: It's finally working, inside .vimrc it was inside the if has('gunrunning') kind of function (i think we can call it), after I got it out it, is finally working, thank you

Comment: @jbernardo You are definitely having the situation of defining your mappings *too early*. Following @FDinoff’s comment you can try to determine what is overwriting your mappings, but almost certainly you can fix your issue with either prefixing them with `autocmd VimEnter *` (so that they will be defined only at vim startup) or putting them in `~/.vim/after/noarrows.vim` (so that they will be defined after most plugins). And do use `nore` versions: though it does not matter here (`<Nop>` cannot be remapped) it must be your habit.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `noremap` and `inoremap` instead of `map` and `imap`, because those disallows nested and recursive use of mappings, so the original meaning of `<left>`, `<right>`, ... will be disabled. It needs `nocompatible` mode.

Explanation in the help of `noremap`:

Map the key sequence {lhs} to {rhs} for the modes
where the map command applies.  Disallow mapping of
{rhs}, to avoid nested and recursive mappings. **Often
used to redefine a command.**  {not in Vi}

Comment: I think the difference between `:map` and `:noremap` will only matter if there is a map defined for `<nop>`, and I do not think that is possible.

Comment: `<Nop>` expands to an empty string, so it is not the case. And you are wrong about the original meaning: it is not disabled, it will be just unavailable in mappings without `nore`. With `nore` it will work regardless of whether you have and how you defined other mappings.

Comment: Maybe my explanation is incorrect, but the solution works for me on Win7 and Debian linux with Vim 7.4